# coastlines don't display using cartopy

Tags: cartopy

I am new to cartopy and tried the examples in the documentation (e.g. http://scitools.org.uk/cartopy/docs/latest/examples/waves.py ). The colour plot displays fine, however, the coastlines are missing when I run the example.

I'm using anaconda on windows and tried installing cartopy via Christoph Gohlke's binaries as well as Rich Signell's conda package on binstar (both of which seem to be the same, resulting in version '0.11.x'). My matplotlib version is '1.3.1'.

How can I get the coastlines to display? Is there anything missing in my installation?

Thanks!

Comment: I had similar problems with the `add_coastlines()` this week, got a HTTP 404 error, and nothing was shown in the plot at all. I worked around it by manually downloading the Natural Earth shapefile and adding the coastlines with:
`ax.add_geometries(list(shpreader.Reader(<filename>).geometries()), ccrs.PlateCarree(), **kwargs)`

Comment: Thanks for this Rutger, I didn't realize cartopy relies on hard-coded urls!

Answer (score 0):

This has been fixed and the package uploaded to the scitools binstar channel.  This issue reflects the change in the url of files on the natural earth website (i.e. changing under our feet).

Comment: Is the package available for windows? The scitools binstar channel says it only contains packages for linux...